# Flickering occurs at places where two vtkcells overlap when trying to display with PraView

Tags: vtk

I want to be able to independently switch the display of unstructuredgrid belonging to different area when displayed in ParaView. Therefore, vtm file was output using vtkMultiBlockDataSet as shown below.
But flickering occurred at places where two vtkcells overlap when trying to display with PraView.
I would be happy if you could tell me how to eliminate flickering.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMultiBlockDataSet> mb =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMultiBlockDataSet>::New();
int numRegions = 2;
mb->SetNumberOfBlocks(numRegions);
mb->SetBlock(0, MakeHexahedron());
mb->SetBlock(1, MakeHexagonalPrism());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter> writer =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLMultiBlockDataWriter>::New();
writer->SetFileName(filename);
writer->SetInputData(mb);
writer->Write();
```

`MakeHexahedron()` and `MakeHexagonalPrism()` return `vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>`, and the surfaces of two vtkcells are in contact with each other.

I am using vtk 7, ubuntu 16.04, paraview 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use a `vtkMultiBlockDataSet` I think that you may want to interact with each element independently by using the [vtkExtractBlock](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkExtractBlock.html) class or its corresponding filter in ParaView. But in my opinion, as long as the datasets share common cells, flickering will occur in rendering.

Another way to tackle this is to append the datasets with [vtkAppendFilter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAppendFilter.html) and use the `Clean to grid` ParaView filter, eliminating common cells by doing so and thus, the flickering.